# Go Gorilla mux to handles API requests

Tags: web-applications, go, router, mux, gorilla

I want to get the map structure from the following Gorilla Mux router input.package main

For example,

```
 router.Methods("GET").Path("/api/{action}").HandlerFunc(httpLog(myHandler))

func myHandler(rw http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    vars := mux.Vars(r)
    log.Println(vars["action"])
}
```

Serves `0.0.0.0:3000/api/input` and this prints out the string `input`

What if I want to be able to receive requests like:

`0.0.0.0:3000/api/v3?id=hello&password=great&product=ipad&confirm=true`

And from this requests, I want to get a map of:

```
map["id"] = "hello"
map["password"] = "great"
map["product"] = "ipad"
map["confirm"] = "true"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will you want me to do?

```
func myHandler(r http.ResponseWriter, q *http.Request) {
    vars := mux.Vars(q)
    fmt.Println(vars["action"])

    fmt.Println(q.FormValue("id"))
    fmt.Println(q.FormValue("password"))
    fmt.Println(q.FormValue("product")) 
    fmt.Println(q.FormValue("confirm"))     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Queries method on you router

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

func main() {
    router := mux.NewRouter().Queries("id", "{id:[a-z]+}", "password", "{password:[a-z]+}", "product", "{product:[a-z]+}", "confirm", "{confirm:true|false}")
    request, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", "http://example.com?id=hello&password=great&product=ipad&confirm=true", nil)

    var match mux.RouteMatch
    router.Match(request, &match)
    fmt.Println(match.Vars)
}
```

[Documentation](http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/mux#Route.Queries)